Is the ⎈ (Control) modifier accessible with the right hand using the CAN/CSA Z243.200 keyboard layout (aka CMS)?
The CSA Group's CSA Z243.200:92 proprietary Canadian keyboard standard for the English and french languages, or CSA keyboard, on which Microsoft based its infamous Canadian Multilingual Standard ("canadien multilingue standard", CMS) keyboard layout, defines the bottom right key as the Group select modifier (⇨) rather than as a right ⎈ (Ctrl key). This makes it the only keyboard layout without a right ⎈ as far as I know.
Unfortunately, this is quite inconvenient for those of us who place their mouse to the left of the keyboard. As this related question shows, it makes several keyboard shortcuts (like Ctrl + Page Up/Down) less accessible.
But most importantly, it makes way less accessible usage of keyboard/mouse combos using Ctrl, since they require to press the left Ctrl using either the same hand which has to click or to reach the left Ctrl using the right hand.
Since such setups are rare, there are several usages of Ctrl + primary click for important functions, such as:

Opening links in new tabs in browsers like Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge
Opening links found in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal
Accessing a function/variable/property/etc declaration from an IDE such as Eclipse or Visual Studio Code

Due to the difficulty of getting used to working without a right Ctrl, I used to remap my menu key (≣) to Ctrl, but I recently stopped doing that, since ≣ has its uses. I found workarounds for a few cases where I missed a right Ctrl, but I am still annoyed by #2 and #3.
I know that I can workaround that by remapping a key (for example using Microsoft PowerToys), but does the standard (or if not, Microsoft's implementation) itself offer a way to simulate Ctrl with the right hand? For example, something like holding Ctrl and Shift simultaneously. I would be quite surprised if it did, but given how complex this layout is and how annoying this is, could someone confirm that it doesn’t?
I am open to alternative ways of invoking Ctrl + primary click, but am not willing to enable Sticky Keys just for that.
